# Why does $\mathbf{j}$ vector not have source in case of direct current?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current

So i was reading the book "Basic Laws of electromagnetism" by I.E. Irodov and he states:

$$\oint \mathbf{j}\cdot d\mathbf{s}=0$$

for a steady state/direct current (where $\mathbf{j}$ is the current density vector and $d\mathbf{s}$ is the area vector), since $-dq/dt= 0$ for a steady state current. But then he goes on to say

> "this means that the lines of vector j do not start or terminate anywhere. The field of vector $\mathbf{j}$ is said to have no sources in case of a direct current."

Since I have done questions on steady state where we have to find the $\mathbf{j}$ vector I don't understand what the author means when he state those facts about vector $\mathbf{j}$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand, or why you find the author's statement confusing?

Comment: @J.Murray i was interested in knowing why vector j does not have a source in case of direct current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the continuity equation tells you that the flux of the current density is the rate of change of the total charge enclosed by the surface,
$$
\frac{dq}{dt} = -\oint_S \mathbf j(\mathbf r) \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf S.
$$
In the steady state, the current is not allowed to depend on time, which means that the right-hand side is completely fixed, i.e.
$$
\frac{dq}{dt} = I_S = \mathrm{const}.
$$
This then implies that $q(t) = q(t_0)+I_S(t-t_0)$ grows linearly with time, with no bounds at all, until it becomes arbitrarily large.

This type of unbounded accumulation of charge is unphysical, as the system will tear itself apart before any of this becomes significant. This is why the requirement of having a source-free current density is considered to be part-and-parcel of the steady-state approximation.